# Cannot upgrade pyhon-html5lib

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, pip

on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS when I run:
`dpkg -l python-html5lib` I'm receiving:

```
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-===============================================================================================
ii  python-html5lib                               0.999-3~ubuntu1             all                         HTML parser/tokenizer based on the WHATWG HTML5 specification (Python 2)
```

Why I'm not able to upgrade it to the newest 0.999999999 using

`sudo pip install html5lib --upgrade`
?

My pip version:
`pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between pip and apt-get packages.
It looks like apt-get repository is not always up-to-date with packages.
I found out the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/431811
and eventually I'm using pip to manage python packages.